# GKAchievement setShowsCompletionBanner exists but gets unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, game-center

I get an "unrecognized selector" crash for [GKAchievement setShowsCompletionBanner:]

As per Apple's GKAchievement Class Reference, showsCompletionBanner is a property of the class.

In my code I use:

```
achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;
```

and that's the only in one place in my code (I double-checked!)

The crash only happens on the live app. I haven't been able to reproduce it.
I can't understand how I can get an unrecognized selector for a property that does exist on the object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I was browsing through support tickets for our app, and I noticed that all users with this issue had iOS 4.x.

Reading the Apple docs more carefully, I found this:

```
showsCompletionBanner
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
```

I'm pretty sure this is my mistake, I should have used respondsToSelector: before using the property.

And this is, I believe, the only way you can get an `unrecognized selector` crash for a class that normally has the called method or property.